# How to add dynamic ref in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have some dynamic `<input>` elements in my dom rendered from for loop in vue. I need to add `ref` property to each of them by appending an Id to each ref like  element1,element2,..etc. How to do this in vue?

```
<div v-for="(result, index) in data" :key="index">
    <input type="text" type="file" ref="element" />
</div>
```

How to add `ref` if `result.id` exists

Comment: I'm doing something similar with my app and it seems to slow things down a lot when dynamically adding refs to my component. At least I think that's what is happening. Curious if you experienced something similar.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Simply use [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) like `:ref="'element' + result.id"` or `` ref="`element${result.id}`" ``.

Check [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/3xj7afgh/1/).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<div v-for="(result, index) in data" :key="index">
    <input type="text" type="file" :ref="'element' + result.id" />
</div>
</div>
```

Edited:
Thanks to Vamsi's edit, I replaced `index` with `result.id`
Edited 8/28:
Thanks to grokpot, I added a sample powered by Template literals.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Thanks a lot for your edit. I changed a few code again to make it work.

Comment: This results in an array.  See https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2044

Comment: you may also use a template literal: ```ref="`element${result.id}`")```

Comment: @grokpot Yes, but don't forget the `:` before `ref`, otherwise the ref will be literally `\`element${result.id}\``

Answer (score 50):

Using `v-bind:ref` or just `:ref`.

Follow below a simple example including how to access a dynamic `ref`

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="inputs" v-for="input in inputs" :key="input.id">
            <input type="text" v-model="input.name" :ref="'name' + input.id">
            <button @click="displayRef('name' + input.id)">
                 Click to see the input ref
            </button>
            <hr>
            <button @click="displayAllRefs">Click to see all refs</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the script:

```html
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                inputs: [
                    { id: Date.now(), name: '', lastName: '' }
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            displayRef(ref) {
                console.log(this.$refs[ref]) // <= accessing the dynamic ref
                console.log('The value of input is:',this.$refs[ref][0].value) //<= outpouting value of input
            },
            displayAllRefs() {
                console.log(this.$refs)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why does one have to access the ref with a `[0]`?

Comment: @TobiasFeil When using refs within `v-for`, `this.$refs[key]` returns an array of elements rather than a single element, even if only one exists. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

Answer (score 22):

You have dynamic refs and have multiple elements. To target any single node just pass the index within method params

```js
     new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        data: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}],
      },
       methods: {
      addNewClass(index) {
      
      this.$refs.element[index].classList.add('custom-class')
    }
  },
    
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

     
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(result, index) in data" :key="index">
   <div ref='element' @click='addNewClass(index)' class='custom-container'>
        
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is brilliant, this is a feature of Vue that I didn't know about. It automagically generates an array of elements. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

Update for Vue [3.2.47+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71414977/refs-inside-v-for-loop-for-vue-v3-2-25-or-above): if specifically you need to access elements of a `v-for`, you can attach a `ref` to an array directly: ([docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for)). [Example code](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<script setup>
// ...
const itemRefs = ref([]);
</script>

<template>
  <Comp v-for="item in list" ref="itemRefs">
    {{ item }}
    {{ itemRefs[2] }}
  </Comp>
<template>
```

If your `v-for` is a list of custom components, be sure to [expose any fields or functions you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73667783/how-to-use-a-template-ref-on-a-custom-component-in-vue-3-compositon-api) with [defineExpose](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose).

If furthermore you require that the list of refs maintain the same order, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72181832/6844235) to be very helpful.

Comment: awesome answer, thanks!