# Vue.js ref inside the v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I tried to use components inside `v-for` loop and init the `ref` to future access some methods of these from parent. Here a simplified code of my case:

```
<template>
    <div class="hello">
        {{ msg }}
        <ul>
            <list-item 
                v-for="item in items" 
                :key="item.id" 
                :value="item.text" 
                :ref="`item${item.id}`"
            />
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ListItem from "./ListItem";
    export default {
        name: "HelloWorld",
        components: {
            ListItem
        },
        data() {
            return {
                msg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App",
                items: [
                    { id: 1, text: "foo" },
                    { id: 2, text: "bar" },
                    { id: 3, text: "baz" },
                    { id: 4, text: "foobar" }
                ]
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            setTimeout(() => this.$refs.item2.highlight(), 1500);
        }
    };
</script>
```

And `ListItem` component:

```
<template>
    <li v-bind:class="{ highlight: isHighlighted }">
        {{value}}
    </li>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "list-item",
        props: ["value"],
        data() {
            return {
                isHighlighted: false
            };
        },
        methods: {
            highlight() {
                this.isHighlighted = !this.isHighlighted;
            }
        }
    };
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
    .highlight {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

It's just renders a few list items and highlights one of them after one and half second. But I got an error: `Uncaught TypeError: _this.$refs.item2.highlight is not a function`
After debug session I've found an interesting fact: refs defined inside `v-for` loop are not a components but the arrays with one component.
What is the logic, what is the f wrapper? Does anyone meet this case? Can somebody give the explanation of this behaviour?
Code presented above works fine with `setTimeout(() => this.$refs.item2[0].highlight(), 1500);`
Must I always pass `[0]`? Is there exist a better way? Help, please.

Comment: `When ref is used together with v-for, the ref you get will be an array containing the child components mirroring the data source.` - is that it?

Answer (score 114):

When using refs with v-for, the component / DOM nodes are stored as an array directly to the variable name so you don't need to use index number in the ref name. So you can do this:

```
<list-item
  v-for="item in items" 
  :key="item.id" 
  :value="item.text" 
  ref="items"
/>
```

And use the refs in your component like this:

```
this.$refs.items[index]
```

Also note that the refs may not be in order and would need to be handled in a different way which is a completely different issue. You can follow that here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4952

Comment: Indeed, you don't need an index in `v-for` loop for `ref`.

Comment: how do I use this with composition api?

Comment: Note that this does not work in Vue 3

Comment: What if you would have multiple elements within the v-for, including an input. and you would want to focus the input. How would you access the specific input within this ref solution.

Comment: Edit I found out how, you can add .children[index] to the end to navigate through the elements inside the v-for

Comment: @yourivdloo Same problem here. I have multiple elements in the v-for loop so I cannot use `ref="items"` for both of them. Can you provide an example of the .children[index] solution?

Comment: @Aros I'm not on that project anymore, however i believe it would look like items.index[0]. Not sure if this is what you meant

Answer (score 54):

For Vue 3 users:

In Vue 3, such usage will no longer automatically create an array in `$refs`. To retrieve multiple refs from a single binding, bind `ref` to a function which provides more flexibility (this is a new feature):

HTML

```
<div v-for="item in list" :ref="setItemRef"></div>
```

With Options API:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      itemRefs: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setItemRef(el) {
      if (el) {
        this.itemRefs.push(el)
      }
    }
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    this.itemRefs = []
  },
  updated() {
    console.log(this.itemRefs)
  }
}
```

With Composition API:

```
import { onBeforeUpdate, onUpdated } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    let itemRefs = []
    const setItemRef = el => {
      if (el) {
        itemRefs.push(el)
      }
    }
    onBeforeUpdate(() => {
      itemRefs = []
    })
    onUpdated(() => {
      console.log(itemRefs)
    })
    return {
      setItemRef
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the doc link: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/array-refs.html

Comment: Please add a line on how to use the ref to, say for example focus on an element, referring its ref

Comment: @JoelGMathew it's very specific request, if you need help then please ping me on skype: `syed_haroon`

Comment: according to the new docs, this feature is available again in vue 3 starting on 3.2.25 https://staging.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for

Answer (score 16):

I tried to handle refs inside v-for by passing index from method:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" @click="toggle(index)">
  <p ref="someRef"></p>
</div>

toggle(index) {
  this.refs['someRef'][index].toggle();
}
```

But in reality it was toggling the wrong elements as indexes of refs are not ordered.

So what I did is added data attribute to ref elements:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" @click="toggle(index)">
  <p ref="someRef" :data-key="index"></p>
</div>
```

Now each ref has its specific data-key. And can be toggled like this:

```
toggle(index) {
  const dropdown = this.$refs['someRef'].find(
        el => el.$attrs['data-key'] === index
    );
  dropdown.toggle();
}
```

Comment: This method will be braking in vue3. So I avoid this if you are using vue3 or later - https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/array-refs.html#frontmatter-title

Comment: This strategy pretty works in a nested v-for case, thanks

Answer (score 8):

I had faced the same issue.

As sobolevon mentioned, the returning value of `$refs.{ref name}` is an array in v-for refs, so my solution is to consider `$refs.{ref name}` is an array with one item only by default, and write `$refs.{ref name}[0].methodToCall()`.

And it works for my case.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone using Vue 3 with Typescript and this ([vuejs/core#5525](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5525)) issue still being open. Based on the other answers, you can do something like this:

**Update:** [vuejs/core#5525](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5525) seems to be fixed so a different solution may be better.

```
<div
   v-for="item in items"
   :ref="addRef"
   ...
</div>

...

function addRef(el: unknown) {
  if (el instanceof Element) {
    participantRefs.value.push(el);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been watching that issue and it looks like it was recently fixed 

Answer (score 5):

Building on [@Syed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292050/syed) answer with **Vue 3** you have the issue stated here [https://vuejs.org](https:///guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for):

> It should be noted that the ref array does not guarantee the same
> order as the source array.

I ran into the issue that I needed the rendered list to have parity with the refs list. This is what I do to solve this issue:

```
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import Comp from './Comp.vue'

  const list = ref([
    {
      name: 'Stripe',
      ref: null,
    },
    {
      name: 'Default',
      ref: null,
    }
  ]);

  function setItemRef(el, idx) {
    if (el) {
      list.value[idx].ref = el;
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, idx) in list">
      <Comp :ref="(el) => setItemRef(el, idx)"/>
      {{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Here is this example running in SFC: [https://sfc.vuejs.org](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 3):

I solved the ordering issue by using a dynamic ref: `:ref="'myRef' + index"`.

If you do this, Vue creates a new array for each item in the v-for, the only element of which will always be the ref you want. You can then access it with `this.$refs['myRef' + index][0]`.

(This won't work in Vue 3.)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.21/vue.js"></script>
<div 
   v-for="(item,index) in items"
   :key="index">
<q-popup-proxy
   ref="qDateProxy">
  <q-date
     :data-key="index"
     v-model="item.date"
     @input="CalendarHide(index)"
     mask="MM/DD/YYYY"
    range>
  </q-date>
</q-popup-proxy>
</div>

<script>
CalendarHide (Val) {
      this.$refs ['qDateProxy'] [val].hide()
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide more details as to what your code does, and why does it answer the question.