# How to access dynamic ref-tagged html elements in Vue.js 3?

Tags: vuejs3

Using the Vue.js 2 api-composition, you have a `.ref` attribute on the `setupContext` argument of `setup()`. As stated in many articles and in this thread : https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api/issues/226 it will **NOT** be available in vue.js 3, and you should declare attributes of the same name as the ref-ed element :

```
<div ref='name'/>

setup() {
  return {
    name : ref(null)
  }
}
```

However, what about when you do not know the ref name at the `setup()` ?

Like this "minimum" example :

```
<div v-for="e in elements" @click="elements.push({name:Math.random(), content:Math.random()})">
  <div :ref="e.name">e.content</div>
</div>

setup(){
   return {
     a_function_called_later(){
       // I can use this.$refs but is there a more "vuejs3" way to do it ?
     }
     // ...???
   }
}
```

Comment: Future searchers: as of Vue 3.2.25+, if you are using a v-for, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72181832/6844235) to be the best solution.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I had the same problem and was asking in the Vue.js Discord about it. Luckily [Carlos Rodrigues](https://twitter.com/pikax_dev) could help me out.

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, i) in list" :ref="el => { divs[i] = el }">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { ref, reactive, onBeforeUpdate } from 'vue'

  export default {
    setup() {
      const list = reactive([1, 2, 3])
      const divs = ref([])

      // make sure to reset the refs before each update
      onBeforeUpdate(() => {
        divs.value = []
      })

      return {
        list,
        divs
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

You can read more about it in the official documentation: https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#template-refs or on my blog: https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/refs-and-the-vue-3-composition-api/

Comment: In the original question the `ref` needs to be on a `div` that is nested within the `v-for` loop, not on the `div` that is doing the loop. There are many use cases for this. How would you go about that?

Comment: Is there any way to set focus() to a control on a certain row number? For example ```divs[1].focus()```

Thanks.

Comment: @andy-bc : the same way : just declare any ref() somewhere in the setup, then, in the template, you just have to do : `:ref="el => { refname = el }"`. refname, can be any reactive stuff, and on each template re-render, the function will be executed, and the el assigned to the ref. Just be sure, if you have complex logic, to clear the refs in a hook so that you are aware if it disapears

Comment: As from v3.2.25, it's been reduced to just this: <div v-for="(item, i) in list" :ref="divs ">

Comment: @Ziad What you described doesn't seems to work on Nuxt 3 (using Vue 3.2.47), I still need to use `:ref="el => { divs[i] = el }"`.

Comment: @Ziad What you described doesn't seems to work on Vue 3.3.4

Comment: @Seno @wei There is a typo, and it should be `<div v-for="(item, i) in list" ref="divs ">`. OP's answer seems to be a workaround fixed in [3.2.47](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71414977/refs-inside-v-for-loop-for-vue-v3-2-25-or-above)