# Refs inside v-for Loop for vue v3.2.25 or above

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I was reading the [documentation of vue 3](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) and I decided to test `refs` in my local development environment. I am using vue version `3.2.31` and set up my project according to [vue official guide](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#local). So for testing "refs" in my component, I just copied and pasted the code in [this url](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) that is the **Playground** of vue site. That means the code of my component is this:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const list = ref([1, 2, 3])

const itemRefs = ref([])

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(itemRefs.value.map(i => i.textContent))
})
</script>

<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list" ref="itemRefs">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

But in the console I receives an empty array. Am I missing something to do to see the output array of texts in `li` tags?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known bug ([`vuejs/core#5525`](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5525)), where array refs are not properly populated.

One workaround is to bind a function that pushes the template refs into the array instead:

```html
<template>
  <ul>                              
    <li v-for="item in list" :ref="el => itemRefs.push(el)">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-template-refs-with-function?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyList.vue)

Or bind the ref array via a wrapper object (as [suggested in the original issue](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5525#issuecomment-1062336844)):

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

const list = ref([1, 2, 3])

const itemRefs = ref([])
          
const skipUnwrap = { itemRefs }

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(itemRefs.value.map(i => i.textContent))
})
</script>

<template>
  <ul>                                 
    <li v-for="item in list" :ref="skipUnwrap.itemRefs">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-template-refs-with-ref-array?file=src/components/MyList.vue)

Answer (score -4):

In `"vue": "^3.2.47"`. It works perfectly, don't need workaround

Comment: Do you know that this bug was repaired exactly in that version? It works in X version is weak answer.