# Vue - Advanced Cropper (Uncaught TypeError: this.$refs.cropper.getResult is not a function)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a crop function for Vue Advanced Cropper like this:

```
            crop() {
            const { canvas } = this.$refs.cropper.getResult();
            if (canvas) {
                const form = new FormData();
                canvas.toBlob(blob => {
                    form.append('files[]', blob);
                    // Perhaps you should add the setting appropriate file format here
                }, 'image/jpeg');

                this.formData = form;

            }

        },
```

My HTML:

```
    <div v-if="cropView">
    <h1>Step 2: Crop images</h1>
    <div class="upload-example__cropper-wrapper">
        <div v-for="image in this.images" :key="image">
            <cropper ref="cropper" class="upload-example__cropper"
                     check-orientation :src="image.src"/>
            <button v-if="image.src" class="upload-example__button" @click="crop">Crop</button>
            <!--<div class="upload-example__reset-button" title="Reset Image" @click="reset()"></div>-->
            <div class="upload-example__file-type" v-if="image.type">
                {{ image.type }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have included the import for Cropper:

```
    import {Cropper} from 'vue-advanced-cropper'
```

Version from package.json:

```
"vue-advanced-cropper": "^2.8.1"
```

Everything works until I get to the crop function where it says the following:
**Uncaught TypeError: this.$refs.cropper.getResult is not a function**

My first thought was, that it may have something to due with looping through multiple images, however it does not work with juse one either. I have tried combining the part from disc and upload to server from here:
https://norserium.github.io/vue-advanced-cropper/guides/recipes.html#upload-image-to-a-server

--- Edit ---

I have export default also, and cropping works, just not getting the results:

```
    export default {

    components: {
        Cropper,
    },
```

Comment: have you returned the cropper from export default?

```
export default {
 components: {
  Cropper,
 },
```

Comment: Yes I have     export default {

        components: {
            Cropper,
        },

- The initial part of getting the cropper to work is fine and I can crop, but when I need to get results it does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are using the same ref name for each element in your v-for it might be possible that this.$refs.cropper is an array. This depends on your version of Vue as well. If that's the case you might have to pass a parameter to your crop function so that the index of the invoking element is known and getResult can be called correctly.

Try console logging this.$refs.
Also maybe see if this thread is useful?
[Vue.js ref inside the v-for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086128/vue-js-ref-inside-the-v-for-loop)

Comment: It appears you might be right! I have tried just for an example to run: this.$refs.cropper[0].getResult() and it looks like it's fetching something now. Now I just need to find a good way to iterate with index or similar so it can get the correct reference I guess. Thank you!

Comment: Nice! You could also do :ref="`cropper + ${itemIndex}`"  and v-for="(image, itemIndex) in the parent

Answer (score 0):

aleksKamb had the right solution. After applying indexes it appears to be working. I edited the v-for to:

```
            <div v-for="(image, index) in this.images" :key="image">
            <cropper ref="cropper" class="upload-example__cropper"
                     check-orientation :src="image.src"/>
            <button v-if="image.src" class="upload-example__button" @click="crop(index)">Crop</button>
            <!--<div class="upload-example__reset-button" title="Reset Image" @click="reset()"></div>-->
            <div class="upload-example__file-type" v-if="image.type">
                {{ image.type }}
            </div>
        </div>
```

And then I edited the cropping function to:

```
            crop(index) {
            const { canvas } = this.$refs.cropper[index].getResult();
            if (canvas) {
                const form = new FormData();
                canvas.toBlob(blob => {
                    form.append('files[]', blob);
                    // Perhaps you should add the setting appropriate file format here
                }, 'image/jpeg');

            }
        },
```