# How to access all refs in component and call their exposed method in Vue 3?

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3

I created validation that runs inside of my formElement component every time I focus out of input.

Now I would like to make extra step and validate whole form on submit before sending data to server. For this I can expose the validation method on formElement and call it from ref variable in parent. This works fine.

The problem is I cannot wrap my head around how to do this without defining ref variable in template and in script for every formElement I have.
My goal is to define one main ref on form and then iterate over child refs and call validate method on each component. How can I achieve this?

**So far I tried this:**

1. I created validation that runs inside of my formElement component every time I focus out of input. I also exposed it so I can call it from parent component by ref. This works fine.

*Very simplified example of formElement:*

```
<template>
  <div ref="formElement">
    ...
    <input :value="" @focusout="validate"/>
    ...
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
  ...
  function validate() {
    // do your stuff here
  }
  ...
  defineExpose({
    validate
  });
</script>
```

2. For the form validation I defined ref on form and also ref for each formElement.

*My approach looks like this (again very simplified example of parent component with form):*

```
<template>
  <form ref="form">
    <form-element ref="name"></form-element>
    <form-element ref="surname"></form-element>
    <form-element ref="age"></form-element>
    <button @click="validateAndSubmit">
      submit
    </button>
  </form>
</template>
<script setup>
  ...
  const form = ref(null);
  const name = ref(null);
  function validateAndSubmit() {
    form.value.name.validate();        // this is not working
    form.value.name.value;             // this will give me value of input from DOM but I dont need it in the scope of what I am trying to achieve
    form.value.name.value.validate();  // this is not working
    name.value.validate();             // this is working, but I would have to define all refs that I have in template which is not scalable
    // do other logic
  }
  ...
</script>
```

Now if I remember correctly, in Vue 2 it was possible to get all refs with $refs variable, but looks like I dont have this option in Vue 3.

Comment: Do you want to write a logic of validation inside `<form-element>` component? I was never using `defineExpose()`. Will it look like your validation function inside the component will have tons of "if" or "switch" statements to know what kind of input it is?

Comment: Yes and no, validation is bound to some value inside of component (in my case model value of form-element), but its written as generic function outside of component so I import it wherever I want to use it. For this I dont need conditional approach. Basically I just say check if this value is valid according to validation with key "required" and I will get boolean and I can do whatever is neccessary (show errors, disable submit buttons etc.) But answer bellow is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You know that you can make a component that will easily pass values to a parent component and there you can hold all logic? It might look like this: `<form-element type="text" v-model="formData.name" @focusout="validate('name')"></form-element>`

Comment: Use case you mention is different to what I was asking for. Read the question again. In your case I would check only validation on one form-element + I would need to create validation in parent which is not necessary. My case is to call validation from parent but let each component handle its validation inside. Another way how to implement this is by shared event bus or store, but this is not something I would like to do as its quite overkill for such a task.

Comment: I know my solution is not what you're asking for, that why I write in comment section not answering the question. You didn't see my validation function, and it validates all form fields when you're not passing any field name as prop. What you are trying to do is an overkill already. You should keep form logic in one component, not in a form component, and all input/select or what ever you will use in a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Refs inside `v-for`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) or [Function Refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs)

Check also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67300497/2487565) for the solution.

Here is the sample doing it both ways.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const FormElement = {
  props: ['id'],
  template: '{{id}}: <input :id="id" /><br/>',
  methods: {
    validate() { console.log('validate(): FormElement ' + this.id) }
  }
}

const App = { 
  components: { FormElement },
  setup() {
    const refs = ref([])
    const validate = () => {
      console.log('validate(): Form')
      refs.value.map(fe => fe.validate())
    }
    const setRef = (el) => {
      refs.value.push(el)
    }
    return { refs, validate, setRef }  
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <form-element v-for="n in 3" ref="refs" :id="n" :key="n"></form-element>
  <form-element id="4" :ref="setRef"></form-element>
  <form-element id="5" :ref="setRef"></form-element>
  <button @click="validate">validate</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Function refs is exactly what I needed! Simple and elegant solution. I was sure I am missing something here, I just did not know the right question to ask and look for in Vue docs. Thank you!